# Why am i getting error of "cannot set property of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

```js
  const quiz = new quiz(questions);

  populate();

  function Question(text, choices, answer){
    this.text = text;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.answer = answer;
  }
  
  Question.prototype.correctAnswer = function(choices){
    return choice === this.answer;
  }

  function Quiz(questions){
    this.score = 0;
    this.questions = questions;
    this.questionIndex = 0;
  }
  
  quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function(){
    return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
  }
  
  quiz.prototype.isEnded = function(){
    return this.questions.length === this.questionIndex;
  }
  
  quiz.protype.guess = function(answer){
    this.questionIndex++;
  
    if(this.getQuestionIndex().correctAnswer(answer)){
      this.score++;
    }
  }
```

When I run this code, it says it cannot set 'getQuestionIndex' to undefined. But didn't Ique set it to 0? I set this.questionIndex to 0 in my Quiz constructor. What am I missing here?

Comment: You have to be consistent in spelling it `Quiz` with a capital "Q"

Answer (score 1):

const quiz = new quiz(questions); should be  const quiz = new **Quiz**(questions);